# Is it possible to change the maximum WIA scanning resolution?

Tags: wia, image-scanner

I have to use the Canon 9000F scanner in a project. I am having some troubles with the TWAIN driver (see: [Are memory issues common when scanning 2400 DPI pictures with TWAIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277805/are-memory-issues-common-when-scanning-2400-dpi-pictures-with-twain)), so I tried WIA as an alternative, but the built in scanning dialog only allows a maximum resolution of 600 DPI, but I know that at least 1200 DPI should be possible.

[image: WIA dialog]

Is it possible to override these values?
Where do the limitations come from? Is this caused by the driver or is this configured somewhere in WIA itself?
If I went to down to a lower level and do all these scanning functions myself would I face the same limitations?

**Question no longer relevant. Decided to use the TWAIN driver.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you've probably found another solution by now, but I stumbled across this post today while I was fighting a similar problem and I'd like to share my workaround.

In my case, we are using a Plustek A320 scanner which supports up to 1600dpi optical resolution.  The actual TWAIN driver seems to cause issues (frequent memory errors like you were seeing) so I wanted to try it using the WIA driver.  Of course, the resolutions that WIA lets you choose only go up to 600.

What I eventually settled on was some driver inf hackery.  I edited the 261U.inf file packaged with the driver installer, adding the bolded line in along with this section:

> [IPCProduct.DeviceData.WIA]
>
> TwainDS=%TwainDSName%
>
> Server=local
>
> MicroDriver="mic-261U.dll"
>
> UI DLL=sti.dll
>
> UI Class ID={4DB1AD10-3391-11D2-9A33-00C04FA36145}
>
> **Resolutions="75, 100, 300, 600, 1200"**

I then manually reinstalled the driver through Device Manager, explicitly selecting the appropriate .inf file.  After a reboot, I'm able to select the 1200dpi resolution when initiating a scan via the Windows Image Acquisition wizard.

Comment: Insightful comment. Haven't tried though, because we decided to use TWAIN.